# jquery append doesn't work with CakePHP's JsHelper

Tags: jquery, cakephp, formhelper

I want to dinamically append some form elements using cakephp's form helper.

What am i missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("a#megyeAdd").click(function(){
            $("div#moreCounty").append(
                <?php echo $this->Form->input('ColleaguesCounty.1.county_id',array('label' => 'Megye')); ?>
            );
        });     
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing quotes on .append parameter.

```
$("div#moreCounty").append("<?php echo $this->Form->input('ColleaguesCounty.1.county_id',array('label' => 'Megye')); ?>");
```

Comment: It still doesn't work. I tried with ' and " but no luck. The function work fine when it has to append the text "asdf".

Comment: it's safe to use single qoutes `'`. Try to check if what is the output of the echo statement if it's what you expect by viewing the source or using firebug

Comment: The output is correct... i think... but here it is:
the odd is that it adds &gt; instead of >

Comment: does it happened before append or after?